# How can set background color of first column of JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, jxtreetable

I have a JXTreeTable and I have implements a custom Renderer.

So I have this code:

```
public class CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese extends JLabel implements TreeCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4842418316518803090L;
    private Font fontTotale = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
    private Font fontNegativo = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setOpaque(true);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        if (row== table.getRowCount()-1) {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setBackground( Color.RED );
            setFont(fontTotale);
        }else if(row != table.getRowCount() && column !=3){
            setForeground( Color.BLACK );
            setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
            setFont(UtilitySwing.getTableFont());
        }else if(row != table.getRowCount()-1 && column ==3){
            //verifico il valore se negativo rosso
            //se positivo blu
            String valore = value.toString();
            if(valore.startsWith("-")){
                setForeground(Color.red);
                setFont(fontNegativo);
            }else{
                setForeground(Color.blue);
                setFont(fontNegativo);
            }
        }
         setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
        return this;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        setOpaque(true);
        if (row== tree.getRowCount()-1) {
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setOpaque(true);
            setBackground( Color.RED );
            setFont(fontTotale);
        }else if(row != tree.getRowCount()){
            setForeground( Color.BLACK );
            setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
            setOpaque(true);
            setFont(UtilitySwing.getTableFont());
        }
         setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "<null>");
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is the code to create a JXTreeTable:

```
    public JTreeTable(){
JXTreeTable talbe = new JXTreeTable();
        talbe .setTreeTableModel(new RandomTextTreeTableModel(listaConti));
        talbe .setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese());
        talbe .setTreeCellRenderer(new CustomTreeTableSpeseXCategoriaSpese());
    }
```

If I try to run this code I can show this:
[image]

If I try to open thi first Node I can see this:
[image]

I want this:
1) Show the complete text
2) How you can see, from the images, I want to set background color gray at all first column. How can I fixed it?

**EDIT**

The post is not duplicate because in the segnalation post there is JTree but in my post, I have JXTreeTable, it is different

Comment: possible duplicate of [Color row in JTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724913/color-row-in-jtree)

Comment: in that post, there is a JTree, in my post there is a JXTreeTable

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the solution might be also applicable or at least may point you in the right direction

Comment: Excuse me but I don't know how I can fixed this problem

Comment: This is indeed not a duplicate, JXTreeTable has a hardwired renderer for the hierarchy column, meaning a custom renderer has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `org.jdesktop.swingx.decorator.HighlightPredicate`s

```
HighlightPredicate hlPred = new HighlightPredicate() {
    @Override
    public boolean isHighlighted(Component renderer,
            ComponentAdapter adapter) {
        return someCondition ? true : false;
    }
};

ColorHighlighter hl = new ColorHighlighter(hlPred, hlBgColor, hlFColor);
treeTable.addHighlighter(hl);
```

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859826/colorhighlighter-on-jxtreetable-change-selection-color-if-predicate-is-true)

Comment: Also worth mentioning, the HighlightPredicate class has several predefined predicates matching odd, even, focused lines and more.